# How to parse import() in dead code

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to dynamic import a module if I'm not in production mode:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  import('bugsnag-js');
}
```

The problem is that in the dev mode I get this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

I noticed that babel doesn't transform `import` to webpack's `require`:
[image]

Howewer, it does, if condition is truly:
[image]

How can I avoid the mistake?

Comment: I presume that Webpack just doesn't bother to parse imports in dead code, since they'll never get run. If you run the `UglifyJsPlugin` on your build (which you probably should be doing in production), the dead code branches will be removed, and so will your error.

Comment: @JoeClay thanks for the tip, but I try to run this in dev mode. Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was a bug in which if you have dynamic import statement inside the false condition then webpack doesn't transpile dynamic imports inside the condition.

This is fixed in Webpack 4: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6786